# Rounding issue with 2 doubles in c#

Tags: c#

Consider the code...

```
double first = 19.99;
double second = 19;
double firstPlusSecond = first + second;
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + firstPlusSecond);
```

The output of this is "Result: 38.99" - which is what I expect

However...inspecting firstPlusSecond in debug, the number is actually 38.989999999999995

Which is messing with calculations elsewhere in the program.

What...?  What have I missed?

Comment: This resolves the issue - but what's up with the double?

Comment: Nope, inspecting 19.99 - it's 19.99...

Comment: Rounding doubles can be painful indeed. Check out this link for a bit in-depth details: http://www.exploringbinary.com/double-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-conversions/ (not C#, but the same still goes)